# Nginx redirect url with param

Tags: nginx

How would I create a redirect that has a url parameter?

For example, I need:
`/testing/?id=123` to redirect to `/testing/123`

I tried
`rewrite ^/testing/?id=(.*)$ /testing/$1 redirect;`
But I just get a `404`.

If I dont use a url parameter and just do something like
`rewrite ^/testing/(.*)$ /anothertest/$1 redirect;` it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
rewrite ^/testing/$ /testing/$arg_id? redirect;
```

This will redirect the user from `/testing/?id=123` to `/testing/123`.